# Tell Hibernate's hbm2ddl to add MySQL enum columns for @Enumerated annotated fields

Tags: mysql, hibernate, enums, hbm2ddl

I'm creating a DB table using hbm2ddl with Java code similar to the following:

```
@Entity
public  class Filter {
    public enum Type {
        TypeA, TypeB;
    }
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
}
```

It works fine, but for "type" a VARCHAR column is created, i.e. the DDL code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filter` (`type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL)
```

But what I want to have is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filter` (`type` enum('TypeA','TypeB') NOT NULL)
```

Is this possible to declare in Hibernate, preferred with annotations?

Or is there a way to extend SchemaUpdate and overwrite the method that renders the alter script part for enumerated field the way I like it?

Background: The same database is used in a PHP part of the project and I want to prevent that invalid values are inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's going to be complicated, since the java.sql.Types, which define the sql types treated by java, does not have enum type (since it's not a standardized type according to SQL-92).

If that **was** the case you could create a hibernate custom UserType extending the EnumType and setting the sqlType accordingly, but since java.sql.Types doesn't handle it I don't see how to use native sql enum.

best regards!

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems there is no way to handle MySQL enums 100% automatically, as pointed out by Lucas on his answer, there is actually a simple way to contour it. You may use `columnDefinition` attribute on `@Column` annotation, which seems to be specifically designed to generate custom DDL code.

See the documentation excerpt describing the attribute:

> (Optional) The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column.
>
> Defaults to the generated SQL to create a column of the inferred type.

The `NOT NULL` restriction is quite standard, and is supported by another attribute `nullable`.

Thus, your property definition would look like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(columnDefinition = "enum ('TypeA', 'TypeB')", nullable = false)
private Type type;
```

Comment: This looks promising but as a comment to PostgreSQL users: this doesn't work on that database system.